# hyperledger node js sdk deploy chaincode in "net" mode

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to develop the app with the node SDK.

The env I used is the vagrant and I ran the membersrv and 4 peer on it.
I have exported the port 7051(for peer gRPC) and 7054(for member) to the host and I ran the app.js provided in fabric/examples/sdk/node at host. I got the following msg [msg at host app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0eS.png) and the err msg showed up at peers log [peers error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM0d5.png).

But I try the REST API to deploy and invoke my chaincode with the same instance, everything work well, I can deploy, invoke and query the chaincode.

Plz, tell me how to fix it, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **chaincode_example02** directory , you are missing the vendor directory that should contain all the dependencies of the go chaincode that you are deploying in net mode. The directory should look like this

```
.
├── chaincode_example02.go
├── chaincode_example02_test.go
└── vendor
    └── github.com
        ├── golang
        │   └── protobuf
        └── hyperledger
            └── fabric
```

Comment: thx! but I follow the instruction
 go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor
 govendor init
 govendor fetch github.com/hyperledger/fabric
 the only thing I got is a vendor folder and a vendor.json.
Do I need to edit the json file by myself?
If so, can you give me a example for the chaincode_example02.go, I have no ideal what I need to write in that file. Thanks a lot!